# Distributed Builds by Bazel

Tags: bazel

How to build a large project by Bazel on two servers to speed up the building process?

> When you have a large codebase, chains of dependencies can become very deep. Even simple binaries can often depend on tens of thousands of build targets.

https://bazel.build/basics/dependencies

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for remote builds starts here:
https://bazel.build/remote/rbe

In particular you might look into the self-service and commercial remote execution services here:

https://bazel.build/community/remote-execution-services